# Intellij Idea NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

When i was run my project via Intellij idea i dont have any error. But when i was make project via Artifacts and run my jar file I show this error:
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup**

I was added jsoup jar Project Structure > Libraries via maven.

```
IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) IC-145.844.1
Build #IC-145.844, built on April 5, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_74-b02 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: Probably making the jar without dependencies.

Comment: yes how i can add dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. add to your POM JSoup dependency:**

dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**2. Add maven assembly plugin:**

to `<build>` section

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

**3. compile and install project:**

example:

```
mvn clean install
```

**4. check `./target` folder for jar with dependencies**

Comment: thank you for reply but where is my pom file? :(

Comment: ok i was solved problem recreate Artifacts with module dependencies

Comment: if you use Maven, ```pom.xml``` must be at project root

Comment: i recommend you to use Maven for dependencies and don't use same features from IDE. Maven is independent tool (identical works with Idea, Eclipse, etc). Standard de-facto